# Get a parameter from HTML before loading is complete

Tags: angular, angular-seed

I have an Angular application based on Seed. I want it to wait for the loading of all data before displaying anything. That is done with a provider in my `app.module.ts`:

```
providers: [
  AlbumConfig,
  UserConfig,
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: (config: AlbumConfig) => () => config.load(),
    deps: [AlbumConfig],
    multi: true
  }
],
```

Problem is the `config.load` (which eventually fires a `resolve(true)`) needs an id given in the HTML page by the server:

```
<rmalbum-app data-id="<?php print $album_id; ?>">Loading...</rmalbum-app>
```

The only way I found to get this parameter is in the `app.component`'s constructor:

```
albumConfig.id= this.elementRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('data-id');
```

The problem is that this constructor is only called after the initialization.

So I either have, chronologically:

- `config.load()`
- "Loading..." disappears
- `app.component`'s constructor is called, I get the id, too late for `config.load`

or, if I remove the APP_INITIALIZER and put the `config.load()` in the component's constructor:

- "Loading..." disappears
- `app.component`'s constructor is called, I get the id
- `config.load()` manually called from the constructor

I don't want that because it means the application is displayed before the config is actually loaded.

Comment: Simply having a  `Router Resolve` will be of good use here i guess.

Comment: What about using `albumConfig.id= document.querySelector('app-element').getAttribute('data-id');` instead?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wait for Angular to initialize the root component, the attribute is already added statically to `index.html` and doesn't need Angular to read.

Just use

```
albumConfig.id = document.querySelector('app-element')
    .getAttribute('data-id'‌​);
```